# Crystal report: Index 0 out of range. - How to fix? -

Tags: crystal-reports

When I try to open crystal report I get the following error.

```
Index 0 out of range.
```

It's my first time to hit that error and I have no clue what causing it.

---

ِAdditional information:

I have NDI Parent when I click at menu it shows a form that contains crystal report, first time of clicking it I get the expected data, but when I close the from and try to open it again it give me that error.

Hopefully it explains more about the problem, if not kindly give me some hint points to explain more about it.

Comment: you need to provide more info on what are you doing in the report that is providing this kind of error. providing only then error information is not sufficient to answer the question

Comment: @Siva Thank you for the feedback, I added further details.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the solution, what caused the problem were in a wrong syntax I used.

I took the object from the form that has crystal-report-viewer in public and it had to be set to private.